# Java Scanner not accepting input when enter pressed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner

The ultimate programming newbie here. Working through a Udemy course on Java. Getting a bit confused with the details of the scanner.

Working on a challenge from the Udemy course, and in this specific case, when I press enter after inputting the information for the scanner, it just goes to the next line and keeps doing that. So I can press enter thousands of times and it just keeps going and going without ever progressing. The same code in another project seems to work, but this one specific project won't.

The problem occurs with the addSong method when entering songName. I've included the main method, incase the mistake I made is in there. The scanner inputs in the main method seem to work fine. Thanks for any help!

Edit for info: The `choice` variable in the main method works as expected. User is expected to input an int for menu selection, and it works as expected. The problem is with the String `songName` in the `addSong` method. Entering any string (so for example "Song 1") and pressing enter, the cursor simply moves down a line in the IntelliJ console. This happens indefinitely. Image attached of the IntelliJ console, showing the cursor several lines down after the input. Sorry if this isn't making much sense! Ultimate newbie.

[IntelliJ Console Cursor Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCnad.png)

```
public class Main {

   private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static LinkedList addSong(LinkedList<Song> Playlist, ArrayList<Album> AlbumList){

    String songName;
    System.out.println("Enter song name: ");
    songName = scanner.nextLine();

    Song newSong = searchAlbums(songName,AlbumList);
    System.out.println("Accepted");
    if(newSong==null){
        System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
    } else {
        Playlist.add(newSong);
        System.out.println("Song added.");
    }



    return Playlist;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Album> AlbumList = createAlbumList();
    LinkedList<Song> Playlist = createInitialPlaylist(AlbumList);

    boolean quit = false;
    int choice;

    while(!quit){
        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Add Song to Playlist");
        System.out.println("2. View Playlist");
        System.out.println("3. View Current Song");
        System.out.println("4. Replay Current Song");
        System.out.println("5. Next Song");
        System.out.println("6. Previous Song");
        System.out.println("7. Remove Song from Playlist");
        System.out.println("8. Quit");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();


        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                addSong(Playlist,AlbumList);
                break;
            case 2:
                viewPlaylist(Playlist);
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

                break;
            case 6:

                break;
            case 7:

                break;
            case 8:
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice. Choose 1-8");
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static Song searchAlbums(String songName, ArrayList<Album> AlbumList){
    Album tempAlbum;
    ArrayList<Song> tempSongList;
    Song tempSong;
    for(int i=0; i<AlbumList.size(); i++){
        tempAlbum = AlbumList.get(i);
        tempSongList = tempAlbum.getSongList();
        for(int j=0; j<tempSongList.size(); i++){
            tempSong = tempSongList.get(j);
            if(tempSong.getSongTitle().equals(songName)){
                return tempSong;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Based on your posted code, you can press enter forever and not update `choice`. Please tell us **exactly** what input you are providing, what output you are getting and how that deviates from the output you are expecting. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how much information was needed. Edited more into the top post. The `choice` variable works. That is updated and appears to work as expected. It is the `songName` String in the `addSong` method which gives the press enter forever issue.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `searchAlbums(songName,AlbumList);`

Comment: The code does print the line `System.out.println("Enter song name: ");` from the addSong method. That is when it allows the user to input text, but pressing enter just keeps going forever. It does print any lines after that.

Comment: please provide the code of the function searchAlbums

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I've added the code for searchAlbums to the bottom of the codeblock in the original post. (Silly newbie question coming), could that affect the pressing enter issue, given the scanner is before the searchAlbums method?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem, in the searchAlbums method. A typo. I am not sure how or why it caused the infinite enter issue, but it does. I need to go read up more on how the scanner class works, as I'm just doing 'monkey see, monkey do' at the moment.

Comment: it's not a problem in the scanner see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem it's not the `Scanner` who is need to be watched it's the loop in `searchAlbum()` method as it doesn't finish due to infinite loop so you keep pressing any thing but it doesn't do anything because the loop is still running, 
So you neet to fix the inner loop as `j` doesn't increment to reach tempSongList

Comment: You are right! Many thanks for helping a newbie and making me look elsewhere.